# List all visible views in an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I've got a test that's failing.

```
onView(withId(R.id.profile_user_name_section)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

When I watch the video for the test, that section IS displayed. So the problem is in the test itself. I'm trying to work out why that's failing, and I wonder if there's an easy way to log all the views that do match isDisplayed. I feel like the answer to that question will explain why my test is failing.